# AngularJS: How do I force Chrome's Dev Console to show me which instruction caused the error?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I very often get error from angular.js, googleapi etc. like "undefined is not a function".

The problem is that I can't figure out how to find the instruction (written by me) who caused the error.
Normally I can use the debugger but there is a huge stack of calls and it's very difficult/long to find the original problem.
This is even more difficult while working with Google API's minified js.

Any clue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what does this have to do with angularjs?

Comment: it has to do that.. most errors come from Angular and its huge call stack

Comment: if you have a specific angular error you are encountering, that would be related to angular.  you could easily put EVERY framework here with this question; jquery, meteor; q; underscore.... there isn't anything angular specific in the issue you are trying to solve.

Comment: ok thank you. I removed the tag. If you downvoted please remove it. thanks :-)

Comment: I didn't, but I suspect the downvote was related to the lack of a concrete question.  I understand what you want is some way to more easily debug your scripts, but the best way for us to help you would be for you to post an example of the kind of error you aren't able to decipher.  There isn't really a magic pill to make debugging easier in every situation....

Comment: well, I get errors very often (like most devs I guess) so I thought it would be useful a more general question (both for me and the community)

Comment: well, I don't know if it helps, but I can say, if you are debugging, you really shouldn't be working with the minified versions of JavaScript files.  If working with minified files is your *only* option (which it isn't, 99% of the time), then the only way you can really know how to trudge through stack traces is trial and error or experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the debugger use breakpoint, or put it in your code with :

```
debugger;
```

If the console is up, the code will stop, helping you to do step by step process.
More info : https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Also **maybe**, you will have more info with a dev version of chrome https://www.google.fr/chrome/browser/canary.html

Comment: thank for your answer. however this implies I'm supposed to guess where the error is originated (which is exactly what I wanted to figure out). right?

Comment: Well, you can put breakpoint before major function and have an incremental approach that way, it's not magic.

Answer (score 1):

In the Sources Inspector of the Chrome DevTools you can press the Pause button (the one on the far right). This will cause the code to stop prior to the exception and maybe this can help you identify the cause of the problem, since you can inspect the scope variables and use the Console to further investigate the call stack.